# Enroll/Authenticate with FACEIO is always failing on enable `Prevent Face Spoofing Attempts (Presentation Attacks) During Authentication & Enrollment`

Tags: face-recognition

I am using FACEIO service for enrolling and authenticating users. And enabled : `Prevent Face Spoofing Attempts (Presentation Attacks) During Authentication & Enrolment`.

When I am trying to detect and prevent the face spoofing by enabling the `Prevent Face Spoofing Attempts (Presentation Attacks) During Authentication & Enrolment` in dashboard, the authentication is always getting failed in order to prevent face spoofing.

Are there any possible solutions to get it worked ?

Answer (score -1):

PixLab’s liveness detection capabilities rely on a machine learning approach that analyzes face images during authentication or enrollment to spot spoof attacks, according to a release.

Because it is a “resource-intensive” feature, FaceIO clarified liveness detection is only available in the PixLab enterprise plans. After subscribing to one such plan, users will be able to specify target applications that can access liveness detection capabilities.

Please [read this article](https://blog.pixlab.io/2023/02/face-spoofing-livneness-detection-and-presentation-attacks-prevention-security-feature-available-for-faceio) to know more.